# Are different screens used for the Toshiba Chromebook CB30-102?

Tags: laptop, display, chromebook

Recently my screen broke on my Toshiba Chromebook CB30-102. I then ordered a new screen online. In the listing, it said the screen was for a "Toshiba Chromebook CB30-102" so I imaged this was all good. However, after it arrived it turned out to be a 30 pin screen. My machine, however, required a 40 pin screen with hooks at a different position. After contacting the seller I was told that the CB30-102 uses either of two very different screens and I simply ordered the wrong screen.

I have tried to look this up online but the [official Toshiba site](http://www.toshiba.co.uk/discontinued-products/toshiba-cb30-102/) does not list details of the screen of this machine. How can I find out which screen(s) fit this particular laptop model?

Comment: Look at the broken screen and all the number, connection, etc. on it and then compare with what you find until you find the correct part you need. Otherwise, see if there's some sort of connection adapter and wire extension is the screen you have fits but just does not line up for the connection points. Just some quick thoughts on your inquiry only.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you note down all the codes you can find on your device as they are, then contact Toshiba support, tell them that you broke the screen of your device, provide them all the details and ask them for the spare part number of the screen. They should be able to figure it out, if necessary they ask you for more details. At worst they will tell you what the spare part number is and that it is out of stock. That's what my experience is with other manufacturers, technical support and 3rd party technicians. There should be a versioning scheme that can be used to identify which components have been used in a particular device, else everyone else would be as puzzled as you are now.

It's awkward to see that you just provided an almost ambigous model number, 
then they did what looked like their best effort to them while apparently already knowing that there is more than one part with completely different specifications and decided *"okay, we will ship this part! thank you for business!"*. Not nice nor trustworthy at all.